# How to calculate a negative feedback loop?

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus

Perhaps this could best be explained as a closed system between two people:

1) For every $1 person A receives, he will give 50% to person B and keep the rest.

2) For every 1$ person B receives, he will give 25% to person A, and keep the rest.

3) Now, person C hands person A $1.  How do I calculate how much money person A and person B will end up with after they keep circularly giving each other a cut of the money they just received to seemingly infinity?

An excel document I made looks like this, where each line is a step in the cycle:

```
Given to A  | A's Total  | Given to B | B's Total
1             1            0            0
0             0.50         0.50         0.50
0.125         0.625        0            0.375
0             0.5625       0.0625        0.4375
```

And so on, until after 14 cycles the differences in totals between cycles diminish and we're left with A's total of 0.571429 and B's total of 0.428571

I can solve this problem with an Excel spreadsheet, but I assume there is a formula to for this sort of feedback problem.

One of my biggest problems finding a solution is that I don't know the correct terminology to describe the problem.

Comment: I think that fallacy to think every math problem/exercise should be classified as a "*this kind of question.*" It's just a question. For this one in particular, just start writing down what happens. $A$ gets a dollar and gives 1/2 to $B$. Then $B$ gives 1/4 of that back to $A$, and so on. If you write it out for a few iterations, you'll see a pattern.

Comment: Thanks Mike.  I've already solved this with Excel.  Seeing the results has not yielded a formula that was obvious to me, though I'm sure one exists.

Comment: The title does not relate to the question, as a start.

Comment: It's not a negative feedback loop. You're trying to find the sum of the terms in an infinite geometric progression. I think that's the "correct terminology" you're seeking.
In your case, A ends up with $X where X = 1/2 + 1/16 + 1/128, etc. So 8X = 4
+ 1/2 + 1/16, etc. Subtact X from 8X  and find that 7X = 4,
X = 4/7. No idea why the question is on hold.

Comment: Thanks stretch.  Supposedly the reason this was on hold was because it was impossible for me to describe the problem without the knowledge of the terminology used.  Despite the moderators, I was able to get help with my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: I misread the question, as was pointed out in the comments. However, formalizing a question like this using recurrence relations is still often a sound strategy, you just have to model it correctly. If I could recommend a general strategy to questions like this, I'd start by writing out the first few terms by hand, try to find a pattern, and realize that pattern in some sequence that you can take the limit of.

I would solve this with recurrence relations.

If person A has been given $ x $ dollars, after one step they have $ \frac{x}{2} $ dollars, as they give half to person B. After the next step, they have $ \frac{x}{2} + \frac{x}{8} $, as person B gives a quarter of what they received to person A. Thus, if we model this with a recurrence relation, we'd have $ a_0 = 1 $, as person A is initially given one dollar, and $ a_{n+1} = \frac{5}{8} a_n $. Then the amount of money person A will have "after" this infinite process will be the limit of this sequence, which is 0. Can you figure out person B's situation from here?

Comment: I think this will be everything I need to go on.  I honestly don't do much math like this so I'll have to do a bit of a refreshing on this topic.  You gave me exactly the starting point I was looking for though.

Comment: Person A doesn't give half of what he *has* to person B, he gives half of what he *receives*. So on the second round, he only gives person B half of $x/8$, not half of $5x/8$.

Comment: You're correct, I misread the question. I'll edit the post to mention this.

Answer (score 0):

This problem can be solved in a lot of ways but one cool way is through Markov chains. Consider the Markov chain with two states $${A, B}$$ where the probability for each state is the chance that any unit of money is in the possession of person A or B. We can define the transition matrix as

$$ P = \begin{bmatrix}
.5 & .5 \\  
.25 & .75
\end{bmatrix} $$ where the first row, second column corresponds to the rate money moves from A to B and the and the second row, first column corresponds to the rate money moves from B to A.

The initial money distribution is $$ M_0 = [1, 0] $$ and the limit as P goes to inf is 
$$ \lim_{n \to \inf} P^n = \begin{bmatrix}
1/3 & 2/3 \\  
1/3 & 2/3
\end{bmatrix} $$

so $$ \lim_{n \to \inf} M_n = M_0 * P_n = [1/3, 2/3] $$

so A ends up with \$0.333 and B ends up with \$0.66.

Comment: That's an interesting way of doing it, but I think you missed part of the problem.  Specifically, that A only gives B a portion of what he "receives", not what he "has".  There for, When A gets 1 from C, A keeps .50 and gives B .50.  Since B receives .50 he keeps .375 of that and gives .125 to A.  Now A "receives" .125 and the loop starts again.  We know from the first time A receives 1, that he will always finish with at least .50.  For the record, my Excel doc has A with .571429 and B with .428571 after 14 cycles.  Edit: had to remove dollar signs for formatting issue.

Comment: Yes I did. It's worth noting .428571... = 3/7 and .571429... = 4/7